# is it posible to run asynchronous python script in a typescript style

Tags: python, python-3.x, typescript, asynchronous

At the moment I have a python script that makes an http request to a microservice. The request takes 3s on average.

This is my python script in a summarized way.

```py
def main():
  response = request_to_MS(url)

  # This process does not need the response of the microservice.
  some_process()

  # This is where i actually need a response from the microservice
  do_something_with_response(response)


main()
```

I would like my script to be able to continue with the code and wait for the request response later similar to typescript.

```js
/**
 * I'd like to write this kind of code in python.
 */
function get_data(): Promise<string>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('This is resolved');
    })
  })
}

async function main(){
  const data = get_data();
  console.log('Data variable stores my promise ', data);
  // Some process
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 ,8].forEach((x: number) => console.log(x));
  // I need the promise value here
  console.log('En el await', (await data).length)
}


void main();
```

Basically what I am looking for is that the time it takes to complete the execution of the process and the response time of the microservice overlap, allowing a better response time in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `request_to_MS(url)` an `async def` co-routine, schedule it as a task with `response = asyncio.create_task(request_to_MS(url))`.

It will begin executing. Now you can continue to run `some_process()`.  When you need `response`, simply do

```py
do_something_with_response(await response)
```

edit: The above will only work if main is also an `async def`, as you can only use `await`s in an async function. Instead of calling `main()`, call `asyncio.run(main())`.

Altogether:

```py
async def request_to_MS(url):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 'some internet data'

async def main():
    response = asyncio.create_task(request_to_MS(url))
    # response is now a Task

    some_process()

    # if response isn't done running yet, this line will block until it is
    do_something_with_response(await response)

asyncio.run(main())
```

An important caveat, `some_process` doesn't have to be a coroutine, but if it is a blocking function (either by CPU or IO) it will never yield any cycles to let `response` run. If it blocks via IO, consider making it a coroutine as well. If there is no async support for whatever low-level IO operations it performs, or if it is CPU bound, consider using asyncio's [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Comment: In my case I have the I/O blocking function `request_to_MS` and the CPU blocking function `some_process`.

As suggested I used `run_in_executor` to run `some_process` and seems to be having the expected results.

Now the question would be why not use `run_in_executor` or `create_task` in both cases?

Comment: Do you know a way to share my example code in this post?

It's so that anyone who comes to this post can see the final result.

Comment: This script runs in a limited machine of 1 processor, will it work the same when i upload it to production?

Comment: ```run_in_executor``` uses a threadpool, so you could run everything in there, but your performance won't be any better than just using threads. If this is targeting a single processor machine, using multiple threads won't improve your performance at all. Instead, asyncio is a paradigm of "cooperative multitasking." All coroutines run in an asyncio loop, which executes in one thread, avoiding the overhead of threads while still accomplishing multitasking. The catch: whoever made the IO library you are using must have explicitly supported asyncio.

Comment: So, general rule of thumb is, if you can run it as a task, you should as it will have minimal overhead. If the IO operation doesn't have low-level asyncio support, you'll have to ```run_in_executor``` which will encounter a slightly worse overhead. I would read up on python's asyncio because it's behavior can be slightly confusing at times but once you "get it" I think it makes a lot of sense. As for your code, I'd just edit it into your original question at the end and I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer.